# How to display a folder of shortcuts into a DataGrid or another control using WPF/c#

Tags: c#, wpf, file, c#-4.0, user-controls

I have a folder (X:\Shortcuts) with shortcuts which could have the following extensions

```
 LNK, URL, EXE
```

I want to show a grid of the shortcuts (Name and Icon) so the user can select them and they will get copied to **H:\Desktop** if it exists otherwise **%USERPROFILE%\Desktop**

I don't need help with copying the file. I need help with displaying the contents of a folder as a Grid in my WPF application

Someone referred me to http://www.wpfsharp.com/2012/10/23/displaying-images-from-a-folder-with-details-in-wpf/

but this assumes the folder is filled with images.

---

My Code-behind code

```
    private ObservableCollection<Shortcut> shortcutItems;
    public ObservableCollection<Shortcut> ShortcutItems
    {
        get { return shortcutItems; }
        set { shortcutItems = value; }
    }

    private ObservableCollection<Shortcut> GetIcons()
    {
        if (shortcutItems == null)
            shortcutItems = new ObservableCollection<Shortcut>();
        shortcutItems.Clear();

        foreach (var item in Directory.GetFiles(path).Where(x => x.EndsWith(".lnk")))
        {
            var icc = Icon.ExtractAssociatedIcon(item);
            shortcutItems.Add(new Shortcut()
            {
                Name = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(item.Substring(0, item.Length - 4)),
                BitMapIcon = System.Windows.Interop.Imaging.CreateBitmapSourceFromHIcon(icc.Handle,
                             System.Windows.Int32Rect.Empty,
                             System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapSizeOptions.FromEmptyOptions())
            });
        }
        return shortcutItems;
    }

    private void getShortCuts()
    {
        shortcutItems = GetIcons();
    }
```

My Entire XAML

```
<UserControl x:Class="Camden_Automated_Help_Desk.AvailableShortcuts"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Camden_Automated_Help_Desk"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
    <Grid>
        <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding ShortcutItems}"  AutoGenerateColumns="False"  >
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Icons">
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Image Source="{Binding BitMapIcom}" />
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" Binding="{Binding Name}" />
            </DataGrid.Columns>    
        </DataGrid>

        <Button x:Name="buttonCopy" Content="Copy Shortcuts" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="165,265,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="125" FontSize="16"/>
        <Button x:Name="buttonReset" Content="Refresh" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,265,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="125" FontSize="16" Click="buttonReset_Click"/>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

I see the header showing the word Icon and label Name but I don't see the Icons or the Name of the Icons in the DataGrid

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to extract the icons from the shortcut/file.

I made the following Shortcut class that has a name property and a bitmap(image) property.

```
public class Shortcut
{
    public Shortcut()
    {

    }

    public string Name { get; set; }


    public BitmapSource BitMapIcom { get; set; }
}
```

In my MainViewModel declared an ObservableCollection of Shortcuts called ShortcutItems and use the following method to populate the collection with 'items' from a folder.

```
private ObservableCollection<Shortcut> shortcutItems;
    public ObservableCollection<Shortcut> ShortcutItems
    {
        get { return shortcutItems; }
        set { shortcutItems = value; }
    }



private ObservableCollection<Shortcut> GetIcons()
    {
        if (shortcutItems == null)
            shortcutItems = new ObservableCollection<Shortcut>();
        shortcutItems.Clear();

        foreach (var item in Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\Users\albErt\Desktop").Where(x => x.EndsWith(".lnk")))
        {
            var icc = Icon.ExtractAssociatedIcon(item);
            shortcutItems.Add(new Shortcut()
            {
                Name = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(item.Substring(0, item.Length - 4)),
                BitMapIcom = System.Windows.Interop.Imaging.CreateBitmapSourceFromHIcon(icc.Handle,
                             System.Windows.Int32Rect.Empty,
                             System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapSizeOptions.FromEmptyOptions())
            });
        }
        return shortcutItems;
    }
```

And in the viewmodel constructor just ShortcutItems = GetIcons();
Make sure your directory path is correct.
It loops through all the files that have the extension ".lnk"(shortcuts). Extracts the icon from the path and converts it to a bitmap. It's not perfect but it retrieves the icons.
I used a DataGrid to test if the icons are displayed. If you use a datagrid just add the ObservableCollection as the Itemssource and create a templatecolumn for the image:
This datagrid is only thing in my XAML, other than this I set the datacontext behind code.

```
    <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding ShortcutItems}"  AutoGenerateColumns="False"  >
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Icons">
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Image Source="{Binding BitMapIcom}" />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" Binding="{Binding Name}" />
        </DataGrid.Columns>
```

This is how using listview would be :

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding ShortcutItems}" >
        <ListView.View>
            <GridView>
                <GridViewColumn Header="Icon">
                    <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Image Source="{Binding BitMapIcom}" />
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                </GridViewColumn>
                <GridViewColumn Header="Name" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Name}" />
            </GridView>
        </ListView.View>
    </ListView>
```

Comment: Can you please post the entire XAML for the DataGrid? Thank You

Comment: I tried your code and i keep crashing here with the following error. {"Object reference not set to an instance of an object."} [ShortcutItems.Add(....]

Comment: I've added the datagrid and all the code relating to the collection in my viewmodel. If it still doesnt work I'll upload the app.

Comment: I used your XAML code and it's not showing anything. I maybe missing something

Comment: I updated my Question with your code and I am not seeing any Icons appearing on my DataGrid

Comment: Ok I finally got it to work. In my constructor, I added this line dataGridShortcut.ItemsSource = GetIcons(); and in my XAML, I added the x:Name property. Is there anyway to style the XAML to not show a grid? My DataGrid is wide and goes to the entire width of the parent window

Comment: Add this to your datagrid : GridLinesVisibility="None" . Simply modify the ui to suit your needs. If you dont want to use a datagrid, use a listview for example. The code to get the icons is the same.

Comment: Thanks for the updated XAML. It does show the icon but in a list. Is there anyway to display them like Windows Explorer Tile View (Windows 7 and up)

Comment: I think a wrap panel should solve your problem. You can take a look at the msdn documentation and http://shihac-sharp.blogspot.co.uk/2012/06/wrap-panel-as-listviews-item-panel.html